# Stuck converting ngResource angular service to Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, vue.js, ngresource

We are migrating our site from old angularjs to using Vuejs.
Step one is to modify our services used throughout the site which all rely heavily on ngResource and convert them into vanilla js code that can be called by Vue.

The challenge is that in addition to making API calls using ngResource they also extending the returning object via prototype.
While using a the module pattern in regular javascript I can mimick the API behaviour of the ngResource service. But I am not clear how to set this up so that it can also support the prototype extensions that are being applied to the returning object (whether a single object or an array).

For example one of our current services might look like this

```
        "use strict";
    
    angular.module("myApp")
        .factory("PortfolioService",
            [
                "$resource", "$rootScope", "$http",
                function($resource,
                    $rootScope,
                    $http) {
                    var Portfolio = $resource("services/portfolios/:Uid",
                        {
                            '_': function() { return Date.now() }
                        }, {
                   'query': {
                        method: "GET",
                        url: "services/portfolios/",
                        transformResponse: $http.defaults.transformResponse.concat([
                            function (data) { return data.Data; }
                        ])
                    }
                });
                      
                    Portfolio.prototype.getPicUrl= function() {
                        return this.ImgBasePath + this.ImgUrl;
                    };
                  return Portfolio;
            }
        ]);
```

Note: that it mames a service call called query but also extends the returning object with a new function called getPicUrl.

I have created a JS equivalent that looks like this

```
const vPortfolioService = (() => {
    var baseapipath = "http://localhost:8080/services/";

    var Portfolio = {
        query: function() {
            return axios.get(baseapipath + "portfolios/");
        }
    };

    Portfolio.prototype.getPicUrl= function () {
         return this.ImgBasePath + this.ImgUrl;
    }

    return Portfolio;
})();
```

The service part works fine but I dont know how to do what ngResource seems to do which is to return a resource from the API which includes the prototype extensions.

Any advice would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my replies to @Igor Moraru, depending on how much of your code base you're replacing, and how much of that existing code base made use of the full capabilities of ngResource, this is not a trivial thing to do. But just focusing on the specific example in your question, you need to understand some vanilla JS a bit more first.

Why does the `Portfolio` object have a `prototype` property when it's returned from `$resource()`, but not when it's created via your object literal? Easy: The object returned by `$resource()` is a function, which in turn also means it's a class, and those have a `prototype` property automatically.

In JavaScript, regular functions and classes are the same thing. The only difference is intent. In this case, the function returned by `$resource()` is intended to be used as a class, and it's easy to replicate certain aspects of that class such as the static `query` method and the non-static (i.e., on the prototype) `getPicUrl` method:

```js
const vPortfolioService = (() => {
    var baseapipath = "http://localhost:8080/services/";

    class Portfolio {
        constructor(params) {
            Object.assign(this, params);
        }
        
        static query() {
            return axios.get(baseapipath + "portfolios/").then(res => {
                // this convert the objects into an array of Portfolio instances
                // you probably want to check if the response is valid before doing this...
                return res.data.map(e => new this(e));
            });
        }
        
        getPicUrl() {
            return this.ImgBasePath + this.ImgUrl;   
        }
    }

    return Portfolio;
})();
```

But the problem is, this probably isn't enough. If you're migrating/refactoring an entire application, then you have to be certain of every instance in which your application uses ngResource, and based on your question, I'm fairly certain you've used it more than this class would allow.

For example, every class created by `$resource` also has static methods such as `get`, `post`, etc., as well as corresponding instance methods such as `$get`, `$post`, and so on. In addition, the `constructor` I've provided for the class is just a very lazy stop-gap to allow you to create an instance with arbitrary properties, such as the properties referenced by the `getPicUrl` method.

So I think you have three options:

- Continue playing with the above class to fit something closer to what you need, and then edit every place in your application where your code relies on the Portfolio Service so that it now reflects this new, more limited class. This is probably your best option, especially if your application isn't that big and you don't have to worry about someone else's code not working
- Analyze the source code for ngResource, rip it out, and modify it so it doesn't need AngularJS to work. Perhaps someone has already done this and made it available as a library? Kind of a long shot I'd guess, but it may work.
- Keep AngularJS in your application, alongside Vue, but only use it to grab the essentials like `$http` and `$resource`. An example implementation is below, but this is probably the worst option. There's additional overhead by bootstrapping pieces of angular, and tbh it probably needs to bootstrap other pieces I haven't thought of... but it's neat I guess lol:

```js
const vPortfolioService = (() => {
    var inj = angular.injector(["ng", "ngResource"]);
    var $http = inj.get("$http"), $resource = inj.get("$resource");

    var Portfolio = $resource("services/portfolios/:Uid",
        {
            '_': function () { return Date.now() }
        }, {
        'query': {
            method: "GET",
            url: "services/portfolios/",
            transformResponse: $http.defaults.transformResponse.concat([
                function (data) { return data.Data; }
            ])
        }
    });

    Portfolio.prototype.getPicUrl = function () {
        return this.ImgBasePath + this.ImgUrl;
    };
    
    return Portfolio;
})();
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. I am going to work with your version of the class and try and go with your first suggestion...ie rework and modify to make it work across our application. We have MULTIPLE services all using ngResource in a similar way so I need to see if this is going to be sufficient. I will play around and hopefully be able to come back and mark this as the answer. Please let me know if any more to add

Comment: I noticed also that In many cases I see that the services are also used just to to make the non-static methods (eg getPicUrl) available on certain objects. For eg var portfolio = new PortfolioService(data) which will return the extended portfolio object. I am not entirely sure why we are mixing both api resourcing and creating object extensions into the same service but will try hold onto that until I see no choice but to separate. From what I can tell you have handled this above. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Object instances does not exposes `prototype` property. Instead you can access it by using:

```
  object.__proto__ // not recommended, or better
  Object.getPrototypeOf(object)
```

`Object.getPrototypeOf()` return object's prototype object, which you can use to assign new properties.

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(Portfolio).getPicUrl= function () {
     return this.ImgBasePath + this.ImgUrl;
}
```

Note: You still can, though, access the prototype of Function() by doing Function.prototype.

UPDATE: Your Portfolio should be a new object, created from the global javascript object, to avoid the issue that @user3781737 has mentioned.

```
 var Portfolio = Object.create({
      query: function() {
        return axios.get(baseapipath + "portfolios/");
      }
    });
```

Comment: The internal `[[proto]]` of OP's implementation of `Portfolio` is the global JavaScript object prototype. Were he to do this, then every single object in the entire application would inherit the `getPicUrl` property. Probably not something you would want to do.

Comment: @user3781737 I've updated my answer. Do you still think it's worth a downvote?

Comment: Unfortunately, there are still issues with this answer, but OP's question in general is hard to answer as it's non-trivial to replace ngResource in every instance. The `Portfolio` returned by `$resource()` that OP is trying to replace is a *class*, with a bunch of explicit and predefined static and instance methods that OP likely needs to account for. The class is then also augmented with the instance method `getPicUrl`. Unless OP says otherwise, your solution should return a class that at least has a static `query` and non-static `getPicUrl` methods.

Comment: I won't fault you for not fully replicating ngResource though. I don't know how extensive OP's code base is or how their application has used that Portfolio Service, but OP's wording and the ways in which Portfolio are augmented implies to me that their application relies on some aspects of `$resource` that they're not fully aware of.

Comment: well, the OP didn't ask to do the entire refactoring of its code. the question was specific for accessing the prototype of the `Portfolio` object,  thanks for feedback, anyway

Comment: Like I said, I'm not faulting you for not fully replicating a whole module. That's a separate issue with the question itself, I think. But your answer still doesn't return a class.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and comments. I will play with the above answer and see if I can get it to behave as expected. What isnt being address is how ngResource returns an object that inherits from the Portfolio class itself. For eg when query() is called a collection of Portfolio objects will be returned which include the function extensions (eg getPicUrl). That seems to be "magic" handled by ngResource which I can't figure out how to replicate.

Comment: and yes user3781737 was correct, I was looking for the return of a class that included both the static query and non-static instance (getPicUrl) methods. Just as mentioned above, in addition the challenge is how that can be returned from the query method itself